# How to output the response HTML data by a jQuery AJAX request?

Tags: php, html, jquery, response, output

I have an online shop with a shopping cart. The cart, which is a `<table>`, refreshes its content after adding an article to the cart.
I use jQuery's AJAX method which receives HTML `<td><tr>` as a response from the called PHP script.
Firebug's console shows the **correct response** from the call.
As you can see in my code, I want to **add HTML to the table**. I can't get it to work.
Do I not understand the AJAX method? I want to add these `<td><tr>` to the shopping cart table.

#### JavaScript (Using jQuery 1.9.1)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/addToShoppingCart.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: content,

    complete: function(data) {  
        $('#shop section table tbody').append(data);
    },
});
```

---

#### Firebug console

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

have tried it using .done()?

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'php/addToShoppingCart.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'html',
  data: content,
}).done(function ( data ) {
  $('#shop section table tbody').append(data);
});
```

Comment: What happens if we get the error while fetching , will done will still called and if yes what you will get in the data.

Comment: done will still be called, and you'll get the error message, if your not sure your script is going to return an error, I'd recommend using success instead, but without further knowledge of the code in addToShoppingCart.php, I assumed he knew that his data would be correct.

Comment: Yup , i wanted to point out the same , because error handling is also important in ajax

Comment: I still believe error handling should be done server sided, not client sided. Gotta let the server do all the handling and let the client just show the data. Although working with success allows you to use status codes, it's just personal preference, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the success also

```
  $.ajax({
       url: 'php/addToShoppingCart.php',
       type: 'POST',
       dataType: 'html',
       data: content, 
       success : function(data) 
      {$('#shop section table tbody').append(data);}
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for `complete` is

```
$.ajax({
url: 'php/addToShoppingCart.php',
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'html',
data: content,

}).complete(function (data) {
    $('#shop section table tbody').append(data);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well inside your cart create table and one tr so that you can display titles at the top

```
<table cellpadding="5" cellpadding="2" border="0" id="cartprod">
    <tr>
      <td width="60%"><b>Product Name</b></td>
      <td width="20%"><b>Quantity</b></td>
      <td width="20"><b>Price</b></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then you can append your content like this

```
function AddToCart(pid)
{
    $.post('php/addToShoppingCart.php',{pid:pid},function(data){    
       $('#cartprod tr:first').after(data); 
    },'html')
}
```

Comment: 'pid' could be add of current item that users is adding to cart And would be send by post method to your php file. if no data to send keep braces empty.